# How can I find and click a button that has no text using React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

Many [React Testing Library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library) examples show how to find and click a button using the `getByText` query, as in:

```
fireEvent.click(getByText("Create"))
```

OR

```
userEvent.click(getByText("Create"))
```

However, it's common to have buttons with no text and only SVG icons, like Material UI's [icon buttons](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#icon-buttons) or [floating action buttons](https://material-ui.com/components/floating-action-button/#floating-action-button). Is there a recommended way to query for and click buttons like these? For context, I'm using the higher-level events provided by the companion [user-event](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event) library.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a case for using getByTestId()?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For icon buttons, add an `aria-label` attribute like below:

```html
<button aria-label='edit'>
  <edit-icon />
</button>
```

Then in your test, pass the accessible name when calling `getByRole()`

```js
screen.getByRole('button', {
  name: /edit/i
})
```

From the [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries/#byrole):

> The accessible name is for simple cases equal to e.g. the `label` of a
> `form` element, or the text content of a `button`, or the value of the
> `aria-label` attribute.

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to query an element, without seeing your hierarchy of elements, it's hard to say. But, there are several ways to query an element, an alternative to using `getByText()` could be `getByRole('button')`. If you want to add a `data-testid` to the element you could use `getByTestId()`. There are some more available queries found here: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries

Comment: I see, so there'll need to be one or more identifiable attributes added to the button like `role`, `aria-label`, `alt`, or `data-testid` to enable one of those other queries. With the Material UI icon button and floating action button examples, they appear to add aria-labels like `aria-label="delete"`, which would enable querying with `getByLabelText`.

Comment: @RomanScher What you want to be thinking is "What text is a screen reader going to read when focus is on this button?" and use the appropriate method for getting it by that text (getByLabelText is often what you want). If your answer to the screen reader question is that it won't read anything, then you should address that.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of different ways to do it, including everyone's favorite fallback, `data-tested`. But if you're using Material UI, you might be looking for the most "MUI" way to do this. Two ideas:

- The [MUI documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/) shows all its buttons wrapped with a `label` element with an `htmlFor` property. You could do this and then use `getByLabelText()`
- Your icon buttons probably have (and should!) a tooltip, and the tooltip text is probably coming from a `title` property. Then you can get the button with `getByTitle()`.

Comment: `title` is not advised as far as I can tell (but can't find a  source back)

Answer (score 2):

For me non of above answers works, what is worked for me is:

```
screen.getByRole('button', { name: /<icon-file-name>/i });
```

In my case the button with only svg file.

Answer (score 1):

The best possible way of finding an element is to simulate the most User oriented approach. So probably User expects the role button and then searches for an icon in your case. That's where semantic HTML plays a role for elements structure inside your component.

MUI buttons also implement a `name` attribute for some icon buttons used inside another component e.g. `Select` and I strongly recommend using this attribute for testing purpose.

Please remember that, your tests should be unaware of implementation, so identification should rely on `name`, `role`, `label` and other "natural" attributes. But if that is not possible using `data-testid` should be your last resort.

A very good overall approach (not only for icon buttons) is to specify a name property alongside role in getByRole query:

```
const listOpenButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /open/i });
```

Also a data-testid approach:

```
const listOpenButton = screen.getByTestId("myButtonId");
```

Comment: I'm using react native paper, based off MUI.  But I don't see any "name" property in the dom, where do you find the name?

Comment: @conor909 I have no prior experience with React Native nor paper, but their docs suggest using `testID` property assuming you are trying to test your button component [link](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/button.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply, yea I ended up using testID, but it just goes against the "test the ui as the user would use it" philosophy